# Finding $1^1+2^2+\cdots+99^{99}\pmod3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Calculate the following numbers in modular arithmetic. Justify your answers.
>   $$1^1+2^2+\cdots+99^{99}\pmod3.$$

I know that $$1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 99^{99} = \sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 1)^{3n + 1} + \sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 2)^{3n + 2} + \sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 3)^{3n + 3}.$$
Then I find that $$\sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 3)^{3n + 3}\equiv 0 \pmod3,$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 1)^{3n + 1} \equiv 3\sum_{n=0}^{32} n(3n + 1)^{3n}+\sum_{n=0}^{32}(3n + 1)^{3n}\\
&\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{32}(3(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n) + 1)^{n}\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{32}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-r}(3)^r(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n)^r1^{n-r}\\
&\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{32}1^n + 3\sum_{n=0}^{32}\left(\binom{n}{1}(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n)+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}(3)^{n-1}(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n)^n\right)\\
&\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{32}1^n \equiv 33 \equiv 0\pmod3,
\end{align*}\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 2)^{3n + 2} \equiv 3\sum_{n=0}^{32} (3n^2+4n)(3n + 2)^{3n}+\sum_{n=0}^{32}4(3n + 2)^{3n}\\
&\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{32}4(3(9n^3 + 18n^2 + 12n) + 8)^{n} \equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-r}(3)^r(9n^3 + 18n^2 + 12n)^r8^{n-r}\\
&\equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}\left(\binom{n}{n}8^n + \binom{n}{1}(3)(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n)+\cdots+\binom{n}{0}(3)(3)^{n-1}(9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n)^n)\right)\\
&\equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}\binom{n}{n}(9-1)^n\equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}(9-1)^n\\
&\equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}\left(\binom{n}{n}9^n+\binom{n}{n-1}9^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}1^n\right)\equiv 4\sum_{n=0}^{32}1^n\\
&\equiv 132\equiv 0\pmod 3.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $$1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 99^{99}\equiv 0 + 0 + 0 \equiv 0\pmod3.$$

Am I correct? Is it correct that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{32}(3n + 1)^{3n + 1} \equiv 0\pmod3$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{32} (3n + 2)^{3n + 2}\equiv 0\pmod3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sum terms of the shape $n^n$ for $n$ running between $1$ and $99$. We consider the cases:

- $n=0$ modulo $3$, then $n^n\equiv 0^n$ is also zero mod $3$.
- $n=1$ modulo $3$, then $n^n\equiv 1^n$ is also one mod $3$.
- $n=-1$ modulo $3$, then $n^n$ is $(-1)^n$ mod $3$.

The corresponding subsums are

- $0+0+\dots+0=0$ modulo $3$,
- $1+1+\dots+1$ (where we add $33$ terms, namely $3\cdot 0+1$, $3\cdot 1+1$, ... $3\cdot 32+1$) modulo $3$, with a total of zero modulo $3$,
- $1-1+1-1+\dots+1=1$ modulo $3$, an alternating sum of reminders modulo $3$, the last one being an even power (for $n=98$). The total contribution here is $1$ modulo $3$.

So we add and get $1$ modulo $3$ in the final.

---

Computer check, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: sum( [ GF(3)(n)^n for n in [1..99] ] )
1
```

Comment: Why it is true that n=0  modulo 3, then n^n≡0^n is also zero mod 3, n=1 modulo 3, then n^n≡1^n is also one mod 3, n=−1  modulo 3, then n^n is (−1)^n mod 3

Comment: For a power $k\ge 1$ we can write $(3a+b)^k$ using the binomial formula. All terms, except for $b^k$, have the factor $3$, so we can omit them modulo $3$. This gives $(3a+b)^k\equiv b^k$ modulo $3$. This is what "they call" arithmetics modulo $3$, or working in the ring $\Bbb Z/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $x \equiv 0 \mod 3$ (and $x \ge 1$), $x^x \equiv 0 \mod 3$.
If $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$, $x^x \equiv 1 \mod 3$.
If $x \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and is even, $x^x \equiv 1 \mod 3$.
If $x \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and is odd, $x^x \equiv -1 \mod 3$.

Comment: How to prove this relation?

Comment: Which part gives you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Exploiting *periodicity* reduces the sum calculation to the sum of the final $3$ terms, as follows.

The terms have period $\,6\,$ by $\!\bmod 3\!:\ (n\!+\!6)^{\large n+6}\!\equiv n^{\large n}\, $ (true for $\,n\equiv 0, \pm 1$ so for all $\,n>0)$

so each period sums to $ 1^2\!+\!2^2\!+\cdots+6^6\equiv \color{#0a0}{1\!+\!1\!+\!0}\!+\!1\!+\!2\!+\!0\equiv \color{#c00}2$

Before $\ 91 = 1 + 6\cdot 15\,$ are $\,15\,$ periods, $ $ having total sum $\,\equiv 15\cdot\color{#c00}2\equiv 0\,$ by $\,15\equiv 0$

Hence the sum is  $\,\equiv\, \underbrace{91^{91}+ \cdots+96^{96}}_{\Large {\rm period\ \Sigma}\ \equiv\,\ \color{#c00}2\ \ } +\, \underbrace{97^{97}\!+98^{98}\!+99^{99}}_{\Large\ \color{#0a0}{1\ +\ 1\ +\ 0}\quad\ }\equiv\, \color{#c00}2\!+\!\color{#0a0}{1\!+\!1\!+\!0}\equiv 1$

**Remark** $ $ The same idea applies for any sum of periodic terms over an interval of $k$ periods plus a partial period. The sum is $k$ times the period sum plus the sum of the terms in the partial period.